# create a third class from existing two classes in css

Tags: css, inheritance

I have 2 classes class A and Class B in CSS..I need to create a 3 class named Class C and add some styles in that in addition to the styles of class A and Class B.Is it possible to inherit Class A and B in C?

Answer (score 6):

It's not possible to inherit classes without dynamically generating your CSS file.

However, you can add your additional style attributes to ClassC and use the following in your HTML:

```
<div class="ClassA ClassB ClassC">
```

Answer (score 4):

Inheritance is not possible with standard CSS. You could use a tool like [less](http://lesscss.org/) to achieve inheritance though.